# Nested div content is not clickable in ie

Tags: css, navigation, nested

So i have a 'meganav' in my site that is essentially a side nav in an  area, that is floated left and takes up a 3rd of the site, then once a parent anchor is clicked, it opens up its child div with a class of 'meganav-div', which opens up to the right and takes up the other 2/3rds of the wrapper area appearing above whatever is in that area.

Currently i have it all working in all browsers, apart from ie6 and ie7, where you can open the first item (div#one) and click on everything just fine, however, anything underneath this (div#two, div#three etc) are not working in that any links inside these divs are not clickable. I have a close button in each div that works on all browsers but not ie6 and 7. The cursor even changes to a pointer on all the anchors, but just will not click. Im assumint that this is something to do with z-index due to the first one working and then not the ones further down the nav list, but i have added the same z-index for all .meganav-div's and still no joy.

Please find the code below. Any help would be much appreciated. thanks. Please find a link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tomiswoot/vqJnY/1/

```
       <section id="herocontainer">
            <div class="hero-white">

                <aside>
                    <ul id="mainnav">
                            <a href="#">Nav item 1</a>
                            <!--===MEGANAV one====-----> 
                                <div id="one" class="meganav-div">
                                    MEGANAV DIV CONTENT HERE
                                </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Nav item 2</a>
                            <!--===MEGANAV two====-----> 
                                <div id="two" class="meganav-div">
                                    MEGANAV DIV CONTENT HERE
                                </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Nav item 3</a>
                            <!--===MEGANAV three====-----> 
                                <div id="three" class="meganav-div">
                                    MEGANAV DIV CONTENT HERE
                                </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Nav item 4</a>
                            <!--===MEGANAV four====-----> 
                                <div id="four" class="meganav-div">
                                    MEGANAV DIV CONTENT HERE
                                </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Nav item 5</a>
                            <!--===MEGANAV five====-----> 
                                <div id="five" class="meganav-div">
                                    MEGANAV DIV CONTENT HERE
                                </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>

            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Can provide a test case? Either a link to the page, or use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)/[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tomiswoot/vqJnY/1/

Sorry guys please find revision of the jsfiddle above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the fact that you have multiple close buttons with the same id=close1 - which makes your html invalid. I changed it to class=close1, now it seems to be working (i also changed positioning a bit for more easy testing)

http://jsfiddle.net/vqJnY/7/